# android page transition laybrary integration null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, transition, pager

Hello everyone i've got this error a nullPointerException error after i tried to integrate the [android-page-transition](https://github.com/xmuSistone/android-page-transition) and i couldn't find it's cause
this is the code where the error is shown PS: it's the same exact caude in the library i just integrated the code into mywork

```
/**
 * Réglage Menu immersive title
 */
private void dealStatusBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        int statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = positionView.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = statusBarHeight;
        positionView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
}
```

this is the error i get when i run

```
11-19 12:11:30.781 16089-16089/mobile.esprit.tn.mobileteam E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: mobile.esprit.tn.mobileteam, PID: 16089
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mobile.esprit.tn.mobileteam/mobile.esprit.tn.mobileteam.Activities.Project.PrjectsCardViews}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
    at mobile.esprit.tn.mobileteam.Activities.Project.PrjectsCardViews.dealStatusBar(PrjectsCardViews.java:129)
    at mobile.esprit.tn.mobileteam.Activities.Project.PrjectsCardViews.onCreate(PrjectsCardViews.java:54)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

the PrjectsCardViews.java:129 is the code i posted above

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the problem it was a dump fault caused by the copy and paste , i dident refere the oncreate to the necessary activity layout

Answer (score 0):

You might have copied the projet but you may forgotten to change
`<com.stone.transition.DragLayout
        android:id="@+id/drag_layout"` when you merged the code in your project check this  out it will work